# Can I multiply a css var with a negative number?

Tags: css

I have a css variable:

```
:root {
    --report-padding-top: 50;
    --report-margin-header: calc(var(--report-padding-top) * -1);
}
```

Can I do this?

```
.header {
    margin-top: var(--report-margin-header) ;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

yes , you can have negative properties in css and the right way to do that is to multiply the value by -1 using `calc()` function:

```
.class {
  margin-top: calc(var(--margin-md) * -1);
}
```